# Creating std::shared_ptr from a reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm running into an object lifetime issue when I write

```
std::ifstream input("/Users/d.a.hosek/CLionProjects/gftodvi/data/cmr10.2602gf");
GFReader reader {std::shared_ptr<std::ifstream>(&input)};
```

When the program concludes, it runs into an issue destroying things in my chain, saying that it's trying to free a pointer that wasn't allocated.

But if I do

```
GFReader reader {std::make_shared<std::ifstream>("/Users/d.a.hosek/CLionProjects/gftodvi/data/cmr10.2602gf")};
```

then the problem goes away. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in the first call sequence when I create my `std::shared_ptr` but I don't really understand what it is. Can someone give me clear explanation of why the first call sequence fails?

Comment: as a workaround, you can pass a `shared_ptr` with no-op deletor. (if you cannot modify `GFReader` to take a non-owning pointer) (and cannot dynamic-allocate `input` e.g. it comes from a parameter)

Answer (score 1):

The first way is intended to take an existing heap-allocated resource and manage its lifetime.  You pass it a non heap allocated resource, violating its rules.

The second creates a new heap allocated resource and immediately manages it.  It even allocates the ref counting block adjacent to the object, to save on calls to `::new`.